# Apache directive to force https

Tags: apache-2.2, seo

I would like to force all visitors to access my website on `https://`

Does this look standard and SEO friendly?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone of the following would work

`RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R]`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,R]
```

Be careful with the R=301 redirect.  Once a browser loads one of those, it stores it FOREVER !  If you ever want to go change the redirect it becomes very hard to do.  Use a R or R=302 instead to start with.

Comment: But if you always want to use https and never http then 301 is what google recommends.